# Why does OpenCV function cvRodrigues2 determines theta with theta = norm(r)? Where r is the rotation axis

Tags: opencv, camera-calibration

To me, the `theta` is the angle of something rotate around the axis(here the r), it is also demostrated in [here](https://www2.cs.duke.edu/courses/compsci527/fall13/notes/rodrigues.pdf).

But why does Opencv's function [cvRodrigues2](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)([MATLAB also](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/mlc-downloads/downloads/submissions/49683/versions/2/previews/LFToolbox0.4/SupportFunctions/CameraCal/rodrigues.m/index.html)) represents the `theta` as `theta = sqrt(rx*rx+ry*ry+rz*rz)`(with `r = (rx,ry,rz)^T`) since the norm is a distance, why can we use it to represent a angle?

Comment: norm is a value. Here it is the length of a vector. Since the direction of the vector is the same, no matter of the length of the vector, the undefined vector length can be used to describe any value like an angle. The direction of the vector describes the rotation axis.

Comment: Thanks, but how do we rotate some other angles?I mean, still I don't understand why we use a length or a magnitude to describe an angle since the vector only describe what an axis we are rotating around, shouldn't the angle be any angle we specify?

Comment: just rescale the vector to get a different angle. The direction (rotation axis) will stay the same. I think it is just a way to represent the rotation axis and the angle in a compact and  easy-to-use way.

Comment: Thank you, I see. I think the point is that the theta is not from the rotation vector r it self but we manually make it happen to be the magnitude of r for the sake of convinience, then we have only 3 parameters instead of 4.